# Как преобразовать USHORT в char?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Не нашел ничего в сети, поэтому спрашиваю здесь.. Как преобразовать USHORT в char? Пока ничего не добился...

```
char src [1024];
...
 USHORT sizep = swap (hdr->iph_length);
   printf("Size: %u",sizep);
   strcat(src, "Size: ");
   strcat(src, sizep);<-очевидно тут ругается компилятор
```

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Строковое представление числа у вас так не выйдет, используйте sprintf.

Comment: не помогло: 

error C2664: 'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'USHORT' to 'const char *'

Comment: Ну да, второй аргумент -- форматная строка. Вы как вызываете-то? См. правильный вариант в ответе @perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в студии 2010 нормально работает, если я правильно вопрос понял конешно

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned short us = 256;

    char buf[10];

    itoa(us, buf, 10);

    cout << buf << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

вывод -----------------

```
256
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

второй вариант с sprintf()==============================

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char buf[10];

    sprintf(buf, "%d", 256);

    cout << buf << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

вывод -----------------

```
 256
 Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```